# send a file to min.io with python and convert to directory

Tags: python-3.x

When I put a zip file in the min.io with the Python library, it becomes a directory. What is the problem and how can I fix it?

...
minio_client.fput_object("bucket_name", file_name, local_file_path)
...

Comment: "What is the problem" ?  Reading your question makes it hard to know (only guess) what you really think the problem is, and what your are expecting. (more info: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.